# PHP use curl_multi_exec(), print HTTP Status

Tags: php

I don't know how use curl_multi_exec(), to print HTTP Status.

First i use this:

```
function testurl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $info[http_code];
}
```

This will print 302, 200...
But if i use this function for 10-15 URLS, the script will work about 15 seconds. This is realy too long.

So i try use this:

```
$nodes = array('http://www.google.com', 'http://www.microsoft.com', 'http://www.rustyrazorblade.com');
$node_count = count($nodes);

$curl_arr = array();
$master = curl_multi_init();

for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{
    $url =$nodes[$i];
    $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
}

do {
    curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
} while($running > 0);

echo "results: ";
for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{
    $results = curl_multi_getcontent  ( $curl_arr[$i]  );
    echo( $i . "\n" . $results . "\n");
}
echo 'done';
```

But i dont now why this don't print nothing if link is good or don't work.

How to use curl_multi_exec() to print, if link is good HTTP Status 200?

Answer (score 2):

This will print the response code of the URL.

```
  $nodes = array('http://www.google.com', 'http://www.microsoft.com', 'http://www.rustyrazorblade.com');
  $node_count = count($nodes);

$curl_arr = array();
$master = curl_multi_init();

for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{
    $url =$nodes[$i];
    $curl_arr[$i] = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl_arr[$i], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_multi_add_handle($master, $curl_arr[$i]);
}

do {
    curl_multi_exec($master,$running);
} while($running > 0);

echo "results: ";
for($i = 0; $i < $node_count; $i++)
{
    $info[$i] = curl_getinfo($curl_arr[$i], CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);    
}
print_r($info)
```